# Call Masonry layout script on elements created by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, masonry

I'm using this Masonry script:

```
var $container = $('.grid');
  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.grid-item',
    columnWidth : '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: 20,
    percentPosition: true
  });
 });
```

It works on a common page load... but I have a part of page which is created by a AJAX call (without a new page load) and Masonry script obviously doesn't know that it should do something with new items... I guess that due to this reason they are displayed overlapped... I tried many things but until today without success :-( Thank you for any advice in advance.

By the AJAX call I'm filling or changing an (empty) div...

the AJAX code:

```
document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = ''; // this div is changed by AJAX and contains all the masonry items
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onload = function() 
{document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = this.responseText;}

url='http://example.com/?var=' + var + '&var2=' + var2;  //paramaters of the new items
xmlhttp.open('GET',url);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: you can recall the grid initialize function on AJAX success code. Share your AJAX code.

Comment: ok, see above, please

Comment: Add your `$container.masonry` code inside of `onLoad` function after innerHTML is performed.

Comment: I tried it... but still it doesn't work... all items are in one column. Should be the masonry script somehow changed?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the masonry script again after adding items to the grid.

```
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    $('.grid').masonry('reloadItems');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it... but still it doesn't work... all items are in one column.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No :( it would be the better option

Comment: I made this change, added to masonry script in AJAX call: ```$('.gridx').masonry('reloadItems')``` . and it does something, all pictures are overlapped, but they have a position: absolute (it should go from the masonry script